# Marlin 1.1.x on Ender 3 changing PREHEAT_1_FAN_SPEED has no effect?

Tags: marlin, firmware, creality-ender-3

I dont want the part cooling fan on during preheat, especially when I'm only heating the bed, it is just unnecessarily loud and serves no purpose at that time.

However when I set `PREHEAT_1_FAN_SPEED` to 0 it has no effect, the fan still spins at full speed as soon as I preheat either the hotend or the bed.

So why is this setting not working and how do I fix this?

I am using the latest version of [Marlin](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/tree/1.1.x/Marlin).

The only one that is defined is the one that I am editing and it is the one that appears on line ~1260 of the stock configuration.h

```
#define PREHEAT_1_FAN_SPEED 0 // Value from 0 to 255
```

And this is the grep result of searching the entire firmware folder:

[image: grep results]

Comment: This question is a little terse and could use some extra information, please update the question by [edit] to include where you set this constant (as it could be that it is overridden later!). The default Marlin `configuration.h` file already contains a `PREHEAT_1_FAN_SPEED` of zero, part cooling fans should therefore never spin unless the configuration is altered. In that effect, which sources do you use? Original Marlin sources or a repository of someone else?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I forgot a critical step:

While I have completely reconfigured the LCD menus, setup custom 25-point mesh leveling, changed a bunch of other numerical values, and flashed the firmware dozens of times, certain values will never be updated unless you remember to **initialize the EEPROM** after the flash!

Honestly I kinda wish they would make it all or nothing but I guess there is limited space so particular things take priority.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is now obsolete now that the OP has updated the question with additional information. It is left here as a possible solution for those who have tinkered with there firmware.*

---

Part cooling fan speed during preheat (from menu) is controlled by the setting

```
#define PREHEAT_1_FAN_SPEED     0 // Value from 0 to 255
```

in [Configuration.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) where a value of `0` implies no rotation, or 0 % and `255` implies 100 %.

If changing this value in your configuration does not result in a reduced fan speed, you could have this constant be defined somewhere else overriding this value.